# Is there a good way to automate periodic exporting from the Stick 'em Up application?

Tags: applescript, automator, script

I'm using an application like Sticky Notes (Stick 'em Up) which has an export feature. I would like to automate a nightly export of the contents. What's the best technology for this - Automator, AppleScript, etc.

I've played a bit and I'm not getting great results with either. Before I dig in and force a square peg into a round hole, is there a good tool for this purpose?

Comment: From where did you acquire **Stick 'em Up**? Is that the exact name of the _application_? What version of the _application_ is it? What's the **URL** of the website you download it from? What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: macOS 10.14.  The exact name of the application is "Stick 'Em Up", v2.1.  I'm not sure exactly where I got it originally (it was years ago) but you can get it here: https://macdownload.informer.com/stick-em-up/